# How to use two email handlers in Google Chrome?

Tags: email, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I am looking for a solution that would enable me to open a `mailto:` hyperlink with one of two email handlers.

Sometimes I want to use Gmail but sometimes I want to use Outlook (default OS X one).

Now I don't have time to switch from one to another and I want to be able to use a modifier key (like Cmd, Alt, Ctrl or Shift) to trigger the use of secondary handler.

How can I implement this?

Comment: I have the same issue - you could probably use the [Mailto: Chrome extensions](http://lifehacker.com/5818958/mailto-for-chrome-opens-email-links-in-gmail-yahoo-or-other-webmail-services) to change your preferred mailto handler, but an ideal solution would let you define a secondary keyboard shortcut for your alternate mailto: client.

Comment: An alternative would be to have a bypass mail handler that asks for which app you want to open, not so good as the modified option. Anyway, I'm open to any answer that solves the problem, I have to switch between work and personal email quite often and I don't want to end-up configuring Gmail account on Outlook.